# How to shake the Google Chrome app with applescript?

Tags: applescript

I have one question.

I found app shake script with applescript.
(in this link: https://gist.github.com/gregferrell/7419080)

And I replace target app name "Terminal" -> "Google Chrome"

But It couldn't work.

I tested "Terminal" and "Finder", Good work!

How do I do?

Thanks.

Best wishes for you.

Comment: `position` is something that Safari does not has and in `Terminal.app` it's deprecated. Use `bounds` instead.

Comment: Awesome! It is really helpful for me. Have a good day~